# Keycloak + Spring MVC - How to access online users?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, wildfly

I am trying to set up an application that uses:

1. Spring 3.2.x

I used to have spring security for the authentication of the users, and I could get all the online users by a bean called SpringRegistryImpl. Here is an example how I could get all the logged in users:

In the controller class I had:

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistryImpl sessionRegistry;
```

and then:

```
List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    for (Object principal : principals) {
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            //Add user to the list with the logged in users (in session).
    }
}
```

Now, I have configured my application’s authentication with keycloak and removed spring-security.

***How can I retrieve all logged in users keycloak?***

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Adding reply from (Stian Thorgersen) as posted in keycloak user list:

---

Hi,

Active user sessions can be retrieved through the admin rest endpoints, as well as through the Keycloak admin console.

You can retrieve all applications with active sessions and number of active users with:

http://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.0.1.Final/rest-api/admin/realms/%7Brealm%7D/application-session-stats/index.html

You can retrieve a list of active users per-application with:

http://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.0.1.Final/rest-api/admin/realms/%7Brealm%7D/applications/%7Bapp-name%7D/user-sessions/index.html

For details on how to use the admin endpoints look at "examples/preconfigured-demo/admin-access-app" in the downloads. There's also a Java admin client lib, which makes it easier to call the admin endpoints, but these methods have not been added